# Hex to decimal conversion in common lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Is there an easy helper function in common lisp to convert from hex to decimal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
(parse-integer "ff" :radix 16)
```

Answer (score 3):

Never mind #xff = 255.....